# Form a query to return information on two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have one table `shop_inventory` and another `shops`. I want to count the number of `DISTINCT zbid` from `shop_inventory` AND the number of rows in `shops` where `cid=1 AND zbid!=0`. I tried it like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.cid) shops,COUNT(DISTINCT b.zbid) buyers 
FROM shops a 
JOIN shop_inventory b ON b.cid=a.cid 
WHERE a.zbid!=0 AND a.cid=1
```

However, this returned 100 shops instead of 2, which is the correct answer. I guess I'm not understanding how `JOIN` works correctly. Can someone offer a fix for this query?

Comment: You seems to need 2 different queries, or one query with 2 sub-queries as these informations are totally independent?!?

Comment: What is the primary key of your shops table?

Answer (score 1):

The `JOIN` on many related rows was throwing off your count of shops.

Try this solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.cid, a.zbid) shops, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.zbid) buyers
FROM   shops a
JOIN   shop_inventory b ON a.cid = b.cid
WHERE  a.cid = 1 AND a.zbid <> 0
```

Comment: This still returns 100 shops instead of 2.

Comment: @KeirSimmons, the JOIN on many rows was throwing off the count of shops. Try it with my revised solution.

Comment: Thanks this works a charm. Why does the extra `a.zbid` in the first `COUNT` make such a difference?

Comment: @KeirSimmons because it's part of your composite primary key. We want to uniquely count the shops that join to the `shop_inventory` table, so we only want to distinctly count the unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If this gets you the count of shops you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS shops
  FROM shops a
 WHERE a.zbid != 0
   AND a.cid = 1
```

Then one way to include a count from another table is to use a correlated subquery. (There are some performance issues with this approach, this works well if the outer query returns a limited number of rows.)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS shops
     , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.zbid)
           FROM shop_inventory b
          WHERE b.cid = a.cid
       ) AS buyers
  FROM shops a
 WHERE a.zbid != 0
   AND a.cid = 1
```

Another approach is to use a join of the subqueries (inline views)...

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS shops
     , c.buyers AS buyers
  FROM shops a
  JOIN ( SELECT b.cid, COUNT(DISTINCT b.zbid) AS buyers
           FROM shop_inventory b
          WHERE b.cid = 1
          GROUP BY b.cid
       ) c
 WHERE a.zbid != 0
   AND a.cid = 1
   AND a.cid = c.cid
```

If those don't return the result set you are looking for, then I have probably  misunderstood the specification.